# Mounting a kubeconfig file using go-client auth method to a container

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I use Google Kubernetes Engine from my Mac & I used to mount my kubeconfig file in a container to use it from some program inside with a simple `-v /Users/johndoe/.kube/config:/home/johndoe/.kube/config`

Recently, some cloud providers, including GCP & AWS changed their kubeconfig auth methods to use the new [client-go credential plugins](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#configuration).

See this [blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke) from GCP.

So now the kubeconfig looks like that :

```
- name: my-cluster
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      command: /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
      installHint: Install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin for use with kubectl by following
        https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/kubectl-auth-changes-in-gke
      provideClusterInfo: true
```

So of course, just mounting the kubeconfig file doesn't work anymore, because the container is looking for `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` (which is a binary returning the token to stdout and that  I can't mount either since the os archs differ).

So I get the following error when running any kubectl command.

```
Get "https://x.x.x.x/version": getting credentials: exec: fork/exec /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gke-gcloud-auth-plugin: no such file or directory
```

This seems like a pretty common use case, how can I work around that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to "hack" this since I wasn't able to find a clean solution.

Simply call the auth plugin and send its output to a file :

```
/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gke-gcloud-auth-plugin > exec_credentials.json
```

Create a shell script to act as a stub (here authStub.sh)

```
#!/bin/sh

cat /tmp/exec_credentials.json
```

Then mount both the shell script and the credentials file with the docker run:

```
docker run \
    -v exec_credentials:/tmp/exec_credentials \
    -v authStub.sh:/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-cloud-sdk/latest/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gke-gcloud-auth-plugin
```

And then it will work for one hour.